# serialize variable merge?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add data of `ExtrasGroupID` variable into `options` serialize variable (or what is other way), how can that be done?

Example below:

```
var ExtrasGroupID = $("#SelectExtrasGroup option:selected").val();
var options = $("#FormExtrasOptionsList").serialize();

$.post("ajax.php", options,
  function(data)  {
        console.log(data)
  });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
var ExtrasGroupID = $("#SelectExtrasGroup option:selected").val();
var options = $("#FormExtrasOptionsList").serialize();

// make sure you set an appropriate key for the new value
options = options + '&' + $.param({ 'select-extras-group': ExtrasGroupID });

...
```

---

Edit: More info on $.param: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/

Answer (score 0):

You could also do a one liner:

```
var ExtrasGroupID = $("#SelectExtrasGroup option:selected").val();
var options = $("#FormExtrasOptionsList").serialize();

$.post("ajax.php", (options = options.split('&')).concat(['extras_group_id='+ExtrasGroupID]).join('&'),
    function(data)  {
        console.log(data)
});
```

Comment: This is kind of dangerous if `ExtrasGroupID` ever contains a value that needs to be encoded.

Answer (score -3):

You can use `.add`:

```
var options = $("#FormExtrasOptionsList").add(ExtraGroupId).serialize();
```

Comment: That did not work. Console Log: `Array ( [option] => Array ( [0] => 40 [1] => 41 ) )`  .. ExtraGroupId is missing

Comment: This adds a string value, `ExtraGroupID`, to a jQuery collection. I'm not sure what the expected behavior here would be.

Comment: I think you wanted `$("#FormExtrasOptionsList").add('#SelectExtrasGroup').serialize()`.

Comment: @jmar777: jQuery would treat the string as a selector, and try to find elements that matched,

Comment: Yes, but that string is the result of `$("#SelectExtrasGroup option:selected").val()`, which is the value of a form field, not a selector.  So, yes, it doesn't actually add a string to the jQuery collection like I said, but simply tries to add the result of a selector that will probably never match anything.

Comment: thought you had extraGroupId as a selector like: http://jsbin.com/akanam/edit would make the `.serialize` easier